# Flexbox, making one element taller than the others?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Basically, I'd like one element to be taller. Is Flexbox even the right tool for this?
I gave all elements the same height, and then in the second item, I changed the height and attempted the min-height, and added !important. But to no avail.

[image: design]

Thank you for the answers. The code was similar to

```
 #container{
    display: flex;
    align-items: baseline;
}
.boxes{
    width: 100px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 10px solid black;
    margin: 10px;
}
#more-height{
   height: 250px;
}
```

but it was only taking classes. IDs helped.

Comment: Flexbox can be the right tool but we need to see your code first. Read the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide (specifically,  how to create a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)) if you haven't already, edit your post, and then we can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do it like this by giving element to increase height an id like this

```css
 #container{
    display: flex;
    align-items: baseline;
}
.boxes{
    width: 100px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 10px solid black;
    margin: 10px;
}
#more-height{
   height: 250px;
}
```

```html
 <div id="container">
        <div class="boxes"></div>
        <div class="boxes" id="more-height"></div>
        <div class="boxes"></div>
        <div class="boxes"></div>
    </div>
```

I suggest that you should include your code in question so that it becomes easy for us to answer

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this result just like this.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: flex-end;
}

.item {
  width: 80px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.item:nth-of-type(2) {
  background-color: red;
  height: 150px;
}
```

Just put your items in a container with a fixed height. Align items to the bottom, and make one of them taller by giving it a bigger height.